How to configure 'userDetailsService' while migrating Spring Security 5.x to Spring Security 6.x
We are migrating our application from SpringBoot2.x to SpringBoot 3.x, as a result we need to migrate SpringSecurity from 5 to SpringSecurity 6.
While migrating I am facing the below error :
In the previous SpringSecurity version 'userDetailsService' used to get autowired as we were extending 'WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter', but it is deprecated now , as a result I am getting configure the userDetailsService error while running the application.
Our application uses Microsoft bearer token , which will be passes to 'getMIToken' end point to get azure Managed Identity token( as we deploy our application in Azure,also we use azure service bus in our application), which is then used to access all our endpoints.
Below is the old version of WebSecurityConfig class:
`
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAsync
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Resource
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Resource
private AzureADUtils azureADUtils;

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
    return new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter(userDetailsService, azureADUtils);
}

@Bean
public RegistrationBean jwtAuthFilterRegister(JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
    registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
    return registrationBean;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin().httpStrictTransportSecurity().disable();
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/getMIToken/**");
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

}`
Old code for JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter:
`public class JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

public static final String UNAUTHORIZED = "Unauthorized";

private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

private AzureADUtils azureADUtils;


public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, AzureADUtils azureADUtils) {
    super();
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.azureADUtils = azureADUtils;
}

private int tokenType(HttpServletRequest request) {
    int tokenType = 0;
    final String requestHeader = request.getHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING);
    final String apiKeyHeader = request.getHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_TOKEN_STRING);

    if (requestHeader != null && requestHeader.startsWith(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
        tokenType = 1; // AZURE TOKEN
    }
    return tokenType;
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String requestHeader = request.getHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING);
    String rolename = null;
    String authToken = null;
    int type = tokenType(request);
    boolean UNAUTHORIZED_ERROR = false;

    switch (type) {
    case 0:
        logger.warn("Ignoring other headers");
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, UNAUTHORIZED);
        UNAUTHORIZED_ERROR = true;
        break;
    case 1:
        requestHeader = request.getHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING);
        authToken = requestHeader.substring(7);
        try {
            rolename = azureADUtils.getRolenameFromToken(authToken);

            if (!SecurityConstants.ROLE_NAME.equalsIgnoreCase(rolename)) {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, UNAUTHORIZED);
                UNAUTHORIZED_ERROR = true;
            }
        } catch (TokenException e) {
            logger.warn("the token is expired and not valid anymore", e);
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, UNAUTHORIZED);
            UNAUTHORIZED_ERROR = true;
        }
        break;
    }


    if (rolename != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {



        if (type == 1) {
            boolean istokenValid = false;
            try {
                istokenValid = azureADUtils.validateToken(authToken);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error in token validation : " + e.getMessage());
            }
            if (!istokenValid) {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, UNAUTHORIZED);
                UNAUTHORIZED_ERROR = true;
            }
        }

    }

    if (!UNAUTHORIZED_ERROR)
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

}
`
New code for WebSecurityConfig (Spring Security 6):
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAsync
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Resource
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Resource
    private AzureADUtils azureADUtils;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter(userDetailsService, azureADUtils);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors(cors -> {})
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated());
  //          .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/getMIToken/**"));
    }
}

New code for JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter:
public class JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter  {

    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final AzureADUtils azureADUtils;

    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, AzureADUtils azureADUtils) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.azureADUtils = azureADUtils;
    }

